# MYSQL - Contar registros por data agrupando por campo

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb

Galera, estou querendo fazer uma contagem por data mas agrupando os registros, imagina uma tabela de registro de acesso a um artigo com os campos:

```
Tabela: analytics
id|id_user|date_time
1 |1      |2022-04-01 10:10:10
2 |1      |2022-04-01 12:10:00
3 |2      |2022-04-01 13:10:00
4 |3      |2022-04-02 10:10:10
```

Como vocês podem ver, temos 3 acessos no dia 01/04, desses o usuário ID 1 acessou 2 vezes, já no dia 02/04 temos apenas 1 acesso, para contar a quantidade de acesso por dia, estou usando essa query:

```
SELECT DATE(`date_time`) as "date", COUNT(*) AS "amount" FROM `analytics` GROUP BY DATE(`date_time`) ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Essa query vai retornar:

```
date       | amount
2022-04-01 | 3
2022-04-02 | 1
```

Agora a questão é, como eu faço para agrupar por usuário para mostrar apenas os acessos únicos por data?
Eu preciso de um resultado assim:

```
date       | amount
2022-04-01 | 2
2022-04-02 | 1
```

Preciso que os 2 registros do usuário 1 fiquem agrupados na data 2022-04-01.
Já tentei várias querys e não achei uma solução.

Outra coisa, estou usando o MariaDB.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

Esta consulta pode ser feita utilizando uma subquery para trazer apenas as datas com ids únicos.

```
SELECT COUNT(date) as amount, date 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_user, DATE(`date_time`) as date FROM `analytics`) as analytics
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC
```

Dessa forma, você terá o resultado desejado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado amigo!